# How can I put 2 discord ids inside a if(message.author.id !=) statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Hello ive been trying to run this code and tried recoding it multiple times but when ever I try to put 2 ids inside of the if(message.author.id != ownerid) return
message.channel.send("You don't have access to this command"); it only registers 1 of the ids
heres my current code:

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === prefix + 'listservers') {
    if(message.author.id != ownerid && altid) return message.channel.send("You don't have access to this command");
//rest of the code

}})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a few different options. Here's how I'd do it, using an array and [Array.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```
const allowedUsers = ["user id 1", "user id 2"]

client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === prefix + 'listservers') {
    if(!allowedUsers.includes(message.author.id)) return message.channel.send("You don't have access to this command");
//rest of the code

}})
```